# Sed print block between line number and next matched pattern

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have text file like this:

```
something something2 something3 {
...
}

something 
something4
this_one 
something5 
{
...
}

something 
something4
something5
this_one 
{
...
}
```

We know the number of line we wont to match from ( we can't use what is on the line as patter ) and we know the next pattern in this case { is somewhere bellow... how do we print that block ?

for example we want line 7 to the next { so the result would be:

```
this_one 
something5 
{
```

I can use sed (preferred) but grep, awk is fine as well, more simple the better. ( bonus point if you can figure out how to look back... so for example we have line 7 and want to match upwards to } )

Comment: On SO we encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so kindly do add the same and let us know then.

Comment: Well that's the issue, I do not know how to do a match between line number and pattern...I can match between two patters just fine, I can match between to line numbers... but not mix it... in simple terms this does not work:  sed -n "7,{p"

Comment: Perhaps use an address and regexp like so `sed  -n '7,/{/p' file`?

Comment: @potong is it possible to "look up" as well ? I mean without reverting the whole file with tac first...

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is _Can someone help me?_ not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: This is not something that sed or grep would be the best tool for. Try to do it in awk as that'll be easier (hint: `NR==7` tests for line number 7 and `/{/` tests for a line containing `{`) and add your attempts to your question.

Comment: To **read backwards** through a file is to *remember* what you have already read reading forwards. `tac` reads forwards through a file that has had its line order reversed. So think about storing the file as you read it and only keeping as much as you need for your solution.